# Почему не работает jquery autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery

В форме есть formgroup:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">найти<star/>*</star></label>
<input class="form-control" name="mark" id="mark" required="true" type="text"/>
</div>
```

В конце файла обработчик:

```
<script>
                $( function() {
                    $( "#mark" ).autocomplete({
                        source: "newJob-search.php",
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            var client = ui.item.label;
                            var clientID = ui.item.value1;
                            var cardName = ui.item.value2;
                            $('#mark').val(ui.item.label;);
                        }
                    });
                } );
            </script>
```

php обработчик:

```
<?
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("sql", $conn);
$q = mb_strtolower($_GET["term"], "UTF-8");

$return = array();
$query  = mysql_query("select clientFIO,id,cardName from clients where clientFIO like '%$q%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return, array(
        'label' => $row['clientFIO'],
        'value1' => $row['id'],
        'value2' => $row['cardName']

    ));
}
echo (json_encode($return));


?>
```

Comment: А он не должен работать?

Comment: Вот это поворот ^_^

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я опечатался, конечно

Comment: Ну тогда как минимум не хватает указания на часть в которой происходит ошибка =) желательно бы с текстом ошибки =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в том-то и дело, что я не знаю, где ошибка :)

Comment: Ага, т.е. вам лень посмотреть в консоль браузера, ответы php скрипта, описать что именно происходит на экране... а мы должны телепатически вычислить где же вы накосячили или опечатались? нам нужно больше информации =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков про консоль как-то не подумал. А по поводу php -> в двух отдельных файлах, без форм и прочего, только с jquery и ui все отлично работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот первая ошибка например, причем в консоле барузера у вас она сразу должна отображаться:

```
$('#mark').val(ui.item.label;);
```

Вот так должно быть:

```
$('#mark').val(ui.item.label);
```

Comment: Точно, исправил, спасибо) но все равно не работает

Comment: @user311608 Ну вполне вероятно, вы же так и не написали какие конкретно ошибки вам выводятся в консоле браузера, и что приходит ответом от сервера на запрос списка, а без этих данных - гадать проблематично.

Comment: В аналогичном скрипте, как я написал в другом комментарии, все данные приходят отлично и все работает.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (newJob:454)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: @user311608 Перевод и пояснение требуется или и так понятно? сразу намекну чтоб вы долго не искали (ошибка не в этом коде скорее всего, а в том что остался за экраном, а именно вы не подключили JQuery UI

Comment: И так понятно, спасибо) А это что может значить?  r.getClientRects is not a function
    at w.fn.init.offset (http://sb-admin/assets/js/jquery.min.js?v=2741496:2:83688)
    at Object.getWithinInfo (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:12124:26)
    at w.fn.init.$.fn.position (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:12143:23)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._suggest  ...

Comment: Тоже конфликт библиотек?

Comment: Вполне возможно что конфликт версий, отсюда не видно версий используемоей библиотеки JQuery, в зависимостях JQuery UI можно глянуть с какой минимальной версией JQuery она работает

Comment: Вообще, у меня были подключены ui v1.11.4 и jQuery v3.3.1

Comment: @user311608 тогда крайне странно что ошибку он находит в `ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js`